# select unique rows based on single distinct column - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want a unique row based on `timesheet_users`. But now the problem is that it is only displaying `timesheet_users` values in template. And  even if i add other fields in `values('...', '...',....) then select unique row does'nt work.

I'm using MySQL so i can't use `distinct('timsheet_user')`- It gives error

> DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

```
TimesheetEntry.objects.filter(
    timesheet_jobs__job_company = self.request.user.userprofile.user_company
    ).values(
        'timesheet_users'
    ).distinct()
```

Models.py

```
class TimesheetEntry(models.Model):
    timesheet_users = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='timesheet_users')
    timesheet_jobs = models.ForeignKey(Jobs, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='timesheet_jobs')
    timesheet_clock_in_date = models.DateField()
    timesheet_clock_in_time = models.TimeField()
    timesheet_clock_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    timesheet_clock_in_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='timesheet_user_clock_in_by')
```

Comment: If you are using mysql then go for RAW query.

Comment: @AnupYadav Thanks for you suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AnupYadav suggested for `raw` query. I came with this MySQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM timesheet_entry t1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT timesheet_users_id, MAX(id) AS latest_id FROM timesheet_entry GROUP BY timesheet_users_id ) t2 ON t1.timesheet_users_id = t2.timesheet_users_id AND t1.id = t2.latest_id
```

This is my View where i used the query

```
class ReportView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'admin/clock/report.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):   
        context = super(ReportView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['reports'] =  TimesheetEntry.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM timesheet_entry t1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT timesheet_users_id, MAX(id) AS latest_id FROM timesheet_entry GROUP BY timesheet_users_id ) t2 ON t1.timesheet_users_id = t2.timesheet_users_id AND t1.id = t2.latest_id')
        return context
```